# Using http binding with CXF

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am getting the following error when using CXF to consume a web service. The exception message is:

```
No binding factory for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/ registered.
```

The WSDL service which I am trying to consume is:

```
<wsdl:service name="MyService">
<wsdl:port name="MyServiceHttpport" binding="impl:MyServiceHttpBinding">
    <http:address location="http://localhost:80/ip/services/MyService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service
```

As seen above, there us http:address instead of soap:address

Answer (score 0):

CXF doesn't support the WSDL http binding.   The cxf-rt-bindings-http module has been removed from the recent CXF releases as it was relatively proprietary and is now replaced with all the REST goodness of the JAX-RS frontend.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am using cxf 2.2  Could you please confirm me from which version onwards support for wsdl http binding was removed?

Comment: @Sandeep last version of cxf-rt-bindings-http is 2.5.9 (based on [release repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-http)), so it should be available with CXF 2.2